# Are posynomial functions convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, geometric-programming

I know that you can transform a posynomial function into an exponential function, which is convex. Does this imply that all posynomial functions are convex?

Answer (score 3):

No, that conclusion does not hold because generally, the product of two
convex functions need not be convex.

As an example, $f(x, y) = x y^{-1}$
(for $x, y > 0$) is a [posynomial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posynomial),
 but not convex:
$$
    f(\frac{1+5}{2}, \frac{1+3}{2}) = \frac 32 
   >  \frac 43 = \frac 12 \left( f(1, 1) + f(5, 3)\right) 
$$

Comment: I agree. Is $\log (f(x,y))$ convex?

Comment: I checked it for myself and it is not convex. Is there a convex transformation of $f(x,y)$?

Comment: @user90593: I don't know.